# Why is mandatory the "Route" attribute on methods of a custom-routed controller?

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing

Consider a fresh Asp.Net Core 2.1 MVC Web app created via the Visual Studio 2017 template. Now, consider a custom view (MyView) and also a controller (ActualController) so that the project structure looks similar to this picture:

[image]

The `MyView` shows nothing special, and it's off the point. However, the page should appear when the user enters an URL like http://(domain)/desired/myview or also via a hyperlink in the home page:

```
<a asp-area="" asp-controller="Desired" asp-action="MyView">MyView</a>
```

Now let's focus on the controller, which is a class *named differently* from what the routing expects:

```
[Route("desired")]
public class ActualController : Controller
{
    [Route("MyView")]  //without this the method won't be called
    public IActionResult MyView()
    {
        return this.View();
    }
}
```

From what I know, by decorating the controller with a `Route` attribute tells the URL resolver to match this class. However, the mapping works only if I explicitly add a (redundant) `Route` attribute on the target method/action. If I remove it, the path won't be found, and the server returns a 404-error.

The question is: why should be mandatory to decorate with `Route` the method, even the action is implicitly defined by the method name (as usual)?

NOTE: is rather simple for me to rename the controller class, but I'd like to know what are the reasons behind this behavior.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are overriding the default route of `[controller]/[action]` with `[Route("desired")]`. Since you don't define an action parameter on controller level, all other routes have to be done explicitly.

Changing the top route parameter to `[Route("desired/[action]")]` should solve it and the method name will be used as parameter. You can still override single actions if you want to name them differently by adding the `[Route("")]` attribute to them.

Also see the [docs (Token replacement in route templates)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/routing?view=aspnetcore-2.1#token-replacement-in-route-templates-controller-action-area) for further description on the route parameters